# jQuery Closest Title

Tags: jquery

Having a hard time to grab a title from a list, here is my code.

```
  <ul class="selected connected-list ui-sortable" style="height: 170px;">
    <li class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible" style=""/>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-element" title="80 Days" style="display: list-item;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"/>80 Days<a class="action" href="#"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

The first list item will not have a tile so it will always be the second list item.

```
$("ul.selected").closest("li").attr("title");
```

But getting no result. Hope you can advise !!

Thank you in advance if you can

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('ul.selected li:eq(1)').attr('title');
```

**closest** doesn't work because it searches in the the element itself and it's parents, and you need to search inside it's childrens.

**eq** matches a single element by its index, and is zero based.

Comment: Man i feel so dumb. Thank you !

Comment: This is far from ideal though, because he has to know (and hard-code) the index of the list item.  I think the other answers are more appropriate.

Comment: @Stodola: "it will always be the second list item.", so this answer will works fine. Besides, this is the same as using :first alone

Answer (score 4):

You can specify that the element should have a specific attribute:

```
$('ul.selected li[title]').attr('title')
```

If you have a lot of li elements with title in the list, you might want to limit the search to the first match. The `attr` method still only gets the attribute value from the first element, but there is no point in putting a lot of elements in the jQuery result that you won't use:

```
$('ul.selected li[title]:first').attr('title')
```

Comment: +1 for the edit to include `:first` because the question here is about finding the "closest" title.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("ul.selected li[title]").attr('title');
```

Will return the value of the first `<li>` that has a title in the `<ul>` *(Note: all* `<li>` *elements with a title will be wrapped in the jQuery object)*. This solution is flexible and doesn't rely on the particular hard-coded position of any particular `<li>` element